# Searching for a 3D Dataset, segmented by 2 or more Experts

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, image-recognition

We are looking for data sets with 3D images, preferably from the medical field. It is important that they have been segmented by more than one person/expert. An example of this is the BraTS Challenge dataset (https://www.med.upenn.edu/sbia/brats2018/data.html) or the LIDC IDRI Dataset (https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/Public/LIDC-IDRI), but we need more datasets for our research.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the [MICCAI dataset](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfwkdSt7hWo_tjHUDu2stDsxWTaWyLJIUiS_iapbtKaydEMIw/viewform). This contains 35 3D MRI scans of brains. The brains have been parcelated into 134 distinct brain regions by professionals.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am not sure if I have seen it correctly, but is there not only one segmentation mask for the respective patient?

Comment: Yeah, it's an aggregation of a few experts annotations.

Comment: I understand, but it's important to us that there are different segmentation masks. Thanks anyway.